# How to provide a clickable link (to some other page) on a dropdown-data-toggle?

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am trying to develop a dropdown data toggle, that can be used to open a dropdown-menu but simultaneously allows the user to click a link.

Currently, the link can only be opened via right-click "open in new tab". However, a left-click on the link always opens the dropdown, even though the browser recognizes the target of my link properly (I can see the target url in the bottom left of my browser).

I Already tried split-buttons, but their layout is not flexible enough.

Basically, I need one button (dropdown-toggle) with two lines.
The first line is an anchor with a link name and an url. 
The second line is the actual label of the button.
(Background: When the user selects a new item from the dropdown, the displayed link and button label are updated by angular.)

```html
<div class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <a href="{{someUrl}}" class="button-link">
        {{link name}}
    </a>
    <div class="button-label">
        {{label}}
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items"> item </li>
</ul>
```

Expected result:
* If the user clicks on the link, I would like to load the linked page.
* If the user clicks somewhere else on the button (no matter whether its first or second line), I would like to open the dropdown menu.

Comment: This sounds like a bad design decision. How will the first-time users of your code know that there is a difference between clicking the text of the button and the surrounding button part of the button? A button should only do one thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, a left-click on the link always opens the dropdown,

The `<a>` tag needs a click handler that stops propagation of the click:

```
<div class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <a href="{{someUrl}}" class="button-link" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
        {{linkName}}
    </a>
    <div class="button-label">
        {{label}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This will prevent the click from bubbling to the `<div>` element that opens the dropdown.

For more information, see

- [MDN Web API Reference - Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: awesome, works as desired. Thanks a lot. There was only a minor change necessary in my implementation (which I cannot explain): I changed $event.stopPropagation() to $$event.stopPropagation(). Could anyone explain, why it helps to put "$" twice?